# FFmpeg remove 2 sec from middle of video and concat the parts. Single line solution

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have a video file that is 22 seconds long.
I want to remove the segment from 10 seconds to 12 seconds.
Then return a concatenated video file of seconds 1-10 and 12-22.

**I want to do this in a single FFmpeg command.**

This is the easy way

Source
https://www.labnol.org/internet/useful-ffmpeg-commands/28490/

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.0 -codec copy -t 10 output_1.mp4
```

**and**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:12.0 -codec copy -t 10 output_2.mp4
```

then create an input file with all the source file names and run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i file-list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

But I'm looking for a one line solution

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For exact trimming, you'll have to re-encode

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='not(between(t,10,12))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -af aselect='not(between(t,10,12))',asetpts=N/SR/TB out.mp4
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: I got error `[Parsed_select_0 @ 0x563493b95040] [Eval @ 0x7ffd628ecba0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'`

Comment: Escape all commas inside expressions e.g. `between(t,` --> `between(t\,`