# Remove a section from the middle of a video without concat

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I cut a section out of a video with ffmpeg?

Imagine I have a 60 second mp4 `A`.

I want to remove all the stuff from 0:15 to 0:45.

The result should be a 30-second mp4, which is composed of the first 15 seconds of `A` directly followed by the last 15 seconds of `A`.

How can I do this without using concat?

I know how I could do it by creating two intermediary files and then using ffmpeg to concat them. I don't want to have to perform so much manual work for this (simple?) operation.

I have also seen the `trim` filder used for removing **multiple** parts from a video. All the usages I've found show that it seems to be very verbose, and I haven't found an example for a case as simple as I would like (just a **single** section removed).

Do I have to use trim for this operation? Or are there other less verbose solutions?

The ideal would of course be something at least simple as `-ss 0:15 -to 0:45` which removes the ends of a video (`-cut 0:15-0:45` for example).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I started from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54192662/3499840 (currently the only answer to ["FFmpeg remove 2 sec from middle of video and concat the parts. Single line solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189099)).

Working from that example, the following works for me:

```
# In order to keep <start-15s> and <45s-end>, you need to 
# keep all the frames which are "not between 15s and 45s":

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
  -vf  "select='not(between(t,15,45))',  setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" \
  -af "aselect='not(between(t,15,45))', asetpts=N/SR/TB" \
  output.mp4
```

This is a one-line linux command, but I've used the bash line-continuation character ('\') so that I can vertically align the equals-signs as this helps me to understand what is going on.

I had never seen ffmpeg's `not` and `between` operators before, but I found their documentation [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

Regarding the usual ffmpeg "copy vs re-encode" dichotomy, I was hoping to be able to use ffmpeg's "copy" "codec" (yeah, I know that it's not *really* a codec) so that ffmpeg would *not* re-encode my video, but if I specify "copy", then ffmpeg starts and stops at the nearest keyframes which are not sufficiently close to my desired start and stop points. (I want to remove a piece of video that is approximately 20 seconds long, but my source video only has one keyframe every 45 seconds!). Hence I am obliged to re-encode. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Seekingwhiledoingacodeccopy for more info.

The setpts/asetpts filters set the timestamps on each frame to the correct values so that your media player will play each frame at the correct time.

HTH.

Comment: Could you please explain what are the `setpts` parameters for? TB/SR/N etc. never seen those before

Comment: I've tried, but I can't fit this into 600 characters. Post it up as another question, and I'll tell you what I know. 

Comment: @jaimet Edit your answer to add information about `setpts`.

Comment: Hm, 'but if I specify "copy", then ffmpeg starts and stops at the nearest keyframes which are not sufficiently close to my desired start and stop points' -> I tried the `-af aselect` filter on an audio file where keyframes shouldn't be an issue, but there copy failed with `Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together`.

Comment: @maxschlepzig [This excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53526514/3499840) should help you.

Comment: Yeah, I was just commenting to point out that your stated reason for why you don't specify `copy` is misleading because even if the keyframes close to your desired start and stop points you **cannot** specify `copy` because _filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together_ ...

Comment: @maxschlepzig If you want to use `copy`/`acopy` (i.e. streamcopying) then you must remove the `aselect` (i.e. filtering) because you can't `filter and streamcopy together`. When _I_ used `copy`, I wasn't using `aselect` so I _did not_ get the error message that you are seeing. You _can_ use `copy` but then you need to use a different method of specifying your segments (i.e. _without_ using a filter such as `aselect`). HTH.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the copy "codec", consider the following approach:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -t "$start_cut_section" -c copy part1.mp4&
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss "$end_cut_section" -c copy part2.mp4&
echo "file 'part1.mp4'" > filelist;
echo "file 'part2.mp4'" >> filelist;
wait;

ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist -c copy output.mp4;
rm filelist;
```

This creates two files from before and after the cut, then combines them into a new trimmed final video. Obviously, this can be used to create as many cuts as you like. It may seem like a longer approach than the accepted answer, but it likely will execute much faster because of the use of the copy codec.

Comment: The problem with the '-c copy' is that some frames are missing from the beginning of each part (as compressed videos rely on previous frames data - so cutting by 'copy' instead of re-rendering simply throws away this trimmed data.

Comment: You can do this in one pass since each line in the filelist can specify range as well. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365857/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video-at-multiple-points. Of course this only cuts on keyframes, but OP explicitly wanted a no-reencode solution

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747935/cut-multiple-videos-and-merge-with-ffmpeg/42750147#42750147. Btw if you are working with mkv file, mkvmerge can do this with cleaner syntax: https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.description.split

Answer (score 4):

For those looking to remove different parts of the video and not just one block, you can pass multiple 'queries' in the command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 \
-vf select='not(between(t\,0\,10))',select='not(between(t\,15\,30))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB \
-af aselect='not(between(t\,0\,10))',aselect='not(between(t\,15\,30))',asetpts=N/SR/TB \
out.mp4
```

Comment: Note: must be no spaces between `select` arguments. For instace the following definition is wrong: `select='not(between(t\,0\,10))', select='not(between(t\,15\,30))'`